# How do I fix SvcUtil generating code with errors in it for a C++/CLI WCF client?

Tags: wcf, c++-cli, managed-c++, svcutil.exe

I've run into a problem with code generated by SvcUtil when generating a WCF client in C++/CLI.

When I run "SvcUtil.exe /t:code /l:cpp http://localhost:2772/mex/" it generates a header file containing the client class below.

```
[System::Diagnostics::DebuggerStepThroughAttribute, 
System::CodeDom::Compiler::GeneratedCodeAttribute(L"System.ServiceModel", L"3.0.0.0")]
public ref class DemoClient : public System::ServiceModel::ClientBase<IDemo^ >, public IDemo
{

    public: DemoClient();
    public: DemoClient(System::String^  endpointConfigurationName);
    public: DemoClient(System::String^  endpointConfigurationName, System::String^  remoteAddress);
    public: DemoClient(System::String^  endpointConfigurationName, System::ServiceModel::EndpointAddress^  remoteAddress);
    public: DemoClient(System::ServiceModel::Channels::Binding^  binding, System::ServiceModel::EndpointAddress^  remoteAddress);
    public: virtual System::String^  GetDemoString() sealed;
};
```

This results in a lot of errors, which I would not have expected given it is generated code.

```
Demo.h(41): error C3766: 'DemoClient' must provide an implementation for the interface method 'void System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Closed::add(System::EventHandler ^)' : see declaration of 'System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Closed::add'
Demo.h(41): error C3766: 'DemoClient' must provide an implementation for the interface method 'void System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Closed::remove(System::EventHandler ^)' : see declaration of 'System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Closed::remove'
Demo.h(41): error C3766: 'DemoClient' must provide an implementation for the interface method 'void System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Closing::add(System::EventHandler ^)' : see declaration of 'System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Closing::add'
Demo.h(41): error C3766: 'DemoClient' must provide an implementation for the interface method 'void System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Closing::remove(System::EventHandler ^)' : see declaration of 'System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Closing::remove'
Demo.h(41): error C3766: 'DemoClient' must provide an implementation for the interface method 'void System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Faulted::add(System::EventHandler ^)' : see declaration of 'System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Faulted::add'
Demo.h(41): error C3766: 'DemoClient' must provide an implementation for the interface method 'void System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Faulted::remove(System::EventHandler ^)' : see declaration of 'System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Faulted::remove'
Demo.h(41): error C3766: 'DemoClient' must provide an implementation for the interface method 'void System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Opened::add(System::EventHandler ^)' : see declaration of 'System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Opened::add'
Demo.h(41): error C3766: 'DemoClient' must provide an implementation for the interface method 'void System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Opened::remove(System::EventHandler ^)' : see declaration of 'System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Opened::remove'
Demo.h(41): error C3766: 'DemoClient' must provide an implementation for the interface method 'void System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Opening::add(System::EventHandler ^)' : see declaration of 'System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Opening::add'
Demo.h(41): error C3766: 'DemoClient' must provide an implementation for the interface method 'void System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Opening::remove(System::EventHandler ^)' : see declaration of 'System::ServiceModel::ICommunicationObject::Opening::remove'
```

Any suggestions on what I need to change or add to correct this?  Should I just add an implementation for the listed interface methods?

Answer (score 4):

Since the link is broken you can use [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20121201050627/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/578860/c-compiler-bug-when-deriving-from-system-servicemodel-clientbase-t) to see the page

The relevant part from the post is

> You should use the following workaround to get a successful compile:
>   Locate the full runtime assembly in:
>   %SysRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.ServiceModel.dll
>
> Copy this dll.
>
> Replace the Reference Assembly in:
>   %ProgramFiles(x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.ServiceModel.dll
>
> Recompiling your project should now succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, just add required TargetFrameworkVersion in .vcxproj

example:
edit your .vcxproj to add TargetFrameworkVersion tag containing v4.7.2
within PropertyGroup at Globals scope

This should work without manually copying any dll.